# Sql date difference query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I need to take diffrence of two dates which are columns in my table:
`LastAIResponseReceivedDate,LastUploadedDate`

I am Using this statement:

```
update Group set AITime=(CONVERT (varchar,(LastAIResponseReceivedDate-LastUploadedDate),121)) where GroupId=2 and Id=5
```

I am getting the time diffrence correctly but my date diffrence is wrong `1900-01-01 01:56:56.427`

How to get the date diffrence correctly

Comment: What are the datatypes? And why are you storing the result as varchar? Also, Group is a reserved keyword, you shouldn't use it as table name. Finally, you tagged `datediff`, do you realise there is a function called `datediff` specifically intended for these calculations?

Comment: If you're intending to get the difference in days(?) between to dates as well, why are you storing this data as a `varchar`? Store data as the correct datatype: integers as an `int`, decimals as a `numeric`/`decimal`, dates and a `date(time)`, etc. `varchar` is **not** a "one size fits all" datatype.

Comment: You might, however, be better off using a (Persisted) calculated column for this though, if you need `AITime` to always have the value of the difference in dates. Then, if one column is updates, `AITime` is too.

Answer (score 1):

Do not understand in your question, that what type of difference you want (Day, month, year).
But this may help you.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, 'Start_date_variable', 'End_date_variable') AS DateDiff;
```

**Syntax As:**

```
DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)
```

Interval can be anything like day, month, year, week, hours, second etc..

Comment: All Date,Month,year,time diffrence i want

Comment: @chiranthvirat so do you have a solution now? If not, please clarify your question, including the points I raised in my initial comment.

Comment: @HoneyBadger still I have Issues
Basically what i want is the diffrence of two dates which s in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
for example difference 2018-02-23 14:35:40.170 and 2018-04-03 08:43:09.833
Get me the command I am fetching this dates from column of my table

Comment: Please edit your question to elucidate. Make sure you address the points in my other comment. Also, what does a difference of `2018-02-23 14:35:40.170` mean? Please add sample data and expected outcome (as formatted text, not picture) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Parse to datetime first, you need

```
Set timediff = DATEDIFF(s, LastAIResponseReceivedDate,LastUploadedDate)
```

Save time difference as second is more convenient for later use. If you want to save in some date format, remember not datetime, time difference is not a 'datetime'.
So,

```
Select CONVERT(varchar, FLOOR(timediff/(3600*24))) + 'D ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, timediff, 0), 114)
```

Comment: Why are you converting to varchar?

Comment: And why, when you're converting to `varchar`, are you not specifying the length?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Oops and thx for pointing out, I probably misunderstand sth, I updated so if this what he really want?

Comment: Set timediff = DATEDIFF(second, LastAIResponseReceivedDate,LastUploadedDate) Statement is throwing an error @ = and at Second

Comment: @chiranthvirat, sorry, typo again, should be 's' instead of 'second'